Why do people speak of yields on bond futures when their expected return is 0?
There are several questions on this site asking about the "yield" of a bond futures contract.
See e.g. How do I calculate yield from a bond futures contract?
However, the expected return of a bond futures contract is zero. Let's say it matures at time $T$ with cash settlement. Since the futures price is the fair price that makes the expected time $T$ payoff equal to zero, then, when entering a futures contract, I don't expect to "earn" anything.
Why then does the yield of a bond futures contract matter? What is it used for?
If the delivery was physical, I'd understand it, since then you can answer the question of "ok, when I actually get this bond, what will the yield be?", but due to cash settlement, you're not getting anything.

This is not essential to your question, but yes bond futures involve physical delivery https://www.cmegroup.com/education/courses/introduction-to-treasuries/learn-about-the-treasuries-delivery-process.html

Interesting, tho ive heard most futures globally are cash-settled.

Bond futures are physically settled, in general in all major markets. Yield and price have an equivalence relationship. The interest in a future yield is the same as why one would care about its price: As a measure of PnL or as a comparsion to another financial product.

Reading online, e.g. https://fastercapital.com/content/Delivery--Demystifying-Bond-Futures-Delivery-and-Settlement.html#:~:text=In%20fact%2C%20most%20bond%20futures,at%20the%20time%20of%20settlement., it says that bond futures are mostly cash settled.
But regardless, imagine we are dealing with a cash-settled bond future. You say "as a measure of PnL" but like I said, the PnL is by construction expected to be zero.  So if I buy a bond future with a yield of 10000000% or a bond future with a yield of 0 %, my PnL is the same in both cases.

It's the effing changes in the yield that matter to P&L of futures. (Or the changes in price).

If the expected pnl is zero and is always zero why bother trading any bond futures at all? And FasterCapital is not correct.

@nbbo2 there's already a measure for that, it's called duration. if you're interested in changes to PnL due to changes in yield, the measure of interest is not the yield itself, its the duration. Good job proving OPs point.

@Junoon45 "it says that bond futures are mostly cash settled." I do not see that anywhere in the page, and I do not think it is true. To answer the question, if you read your linked answer, the "yield" is based on the yield of the underlying bond; it is not the "yield" relative to your initial investment, which as you state is zero.

@Attack68  "If the expected pnl is zero and is always zero why bother trading any bond futures at all?" The expected (read: average) return of any fairly priced future is zero. It's not about guaranteeing a return, it's about guaranteeing a price at which to buy the bond later. That price may be above or below the market price at the time. On average, you'd break even.  Investors typically use bond futures to hedge against interest rate or other bond-related risk, though some may use them to speculate (just like commodity and other physical futures)

I was employing antiphrasis, but none-the-less I am sure your clarification and answer will be well received.

@Attack68 Apologies - I did not discern that. But should have from the rep :)

The "yield" on a Bond Futures trade is based on the yield of the underlying bond that you get (or would get for cash settlement), accounting for conversion factors and other characteristics of the future. It is not the "yield" in terms of return on investment that you get from the future itself, since there is no cash spent upfront.

Why then does the yield of a bond futures contract matter? What is it used for?

It's used to evaluate what type of yield you can expect from the bond that you would buy, to evaluate what the fair futures price would be.
Individual bonds are commonly valued in terms of "yield" rather than price, so you could think of the "yield" as analogous to the "price" of, say, an oil futures contract, where you enter into a contract to buy (or sell) oil at a specific price sometime in the future. With a bond future, you are entering into a contract to buy or sell a bond at a specific price, which translates to an equivalent yield based on the price, term, and coupon rate of the bond.
A bond future is not always for one specific bond only, but from the "Cheapest to Deliver" of several eligible bonds, which have different coupons and maturities.  Since the "price" of two bonds with different coupons or maturities are not directly comparable, but yield is, the "yield" of a bond future allows one to see what type of return they can expect from the bond regardless of what price is actually paid.
